# How do you make your text open to a new page when you click on it using pure html?

Tags: html

I know this seems very basic but please help me out im doing this for my computer subject project. THANKS !

Answer (score 2):

You can use a link in the HTML code. It will go to the desired url -

```
<a href="urltoyourpage" target="_blank">My Page</a>
```

For example lets say you want to go to youtube then -

`<a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank">Youtube Link</a>`

Official docs at MDN -
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: @luigi if you found my answer useful, please upvote(click the upward pointing triangle) and click the check button

Comment: u answered first, it's correct so u should get the points

Comment: Answered first without the target attribute which was the most important part, but who's keeping track :/

Answer (score 0):

You use the `target` attribute:

```
<a href="/url" target="_blank"></a>
```

Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp